# DeviceIoControl() returned data meaning

Tags: winapi, reverse-engineering, createfile, ollydbg

I've been reversing an exemplary application given in class & I'm facing a problem trying to find out what the `DeviceIoControl()` function is returning in the `Output Buffer` & since `DeviceIoControl()` is often used after calling `CreateFile()`, i have to discuss about that last one.
Those are the steps the program goes through:

1. The program opens `C:` drive with `READ|WRITE` access & `READ|WRITE` shared mode (`CreateFile()` function).
2. Then fills an input buffer (which seems to be a structure) with certain data I'll be posting at the end.
3. Specifies `Input Buffer` & `Output Buffer` sizes.
4. And finally calling `DeviceIoControl()` with control code: `4D004h`

By looking at the data returned in the `Output Buffer`, it seems like it's all about hard drive info like: manufacturer, model name...etc

This is the data block returned:
[image: Data Returned]

The most important string which is kept for later use is: `Z2P1S4PJ` and i have no idea what it means !!

For the rest of supplements:

[image: CreateFile]

[image: ControlIODevice]

[image: Input Buffer content]

Comment: I forgot to comment the last pictures .The first one (at the end) is the call to CreateFile.The second one is the call to ControlIoDevice.The third and the last is Input Buffer data.

Comment: is it a call to `ControlIoDevice` or `DeviceIoControl`? MSDN has no help about the first.

Comment: @Seki It is `DeviceIoControl`,im sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Seki i added a comment to your answer,please check it out!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching, and *if* we are talking of the `dwIoControlCode` of the winapi [`DeviceIoControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) function, it seems that the `4D004` code is defined as [`IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560519(v=vs.85).aspx), so it let sending some commands to SCSI devices. The detail of the command should be in the buffer pointed by the parameters pair `lpInBuffer` / `nInBufferSize`.

It will be difficult to tell what command exactly, without knowing the device, and I do not know the details of SCSI interface management.

Comment: I've already found myself reading the same info about that  `IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH` command but unfortunately,i have no idea about SCSI devices.The other thing is that the handle that `DeviceIoControl` uses is a handle to a volume ("C:\") ,so it must be a hard drive command & the hard drive is a SATA  device (Because as it seems the program tries to open some SCSI device but it fails to retreive requested data,so it proceeds to a second choice which is opening the ("C:\") & requesting data with that code & the data is successfully returned (some hard drive info-see Capture above).